# Regarding passing array pointer to constructor and assigning it to class' pointer variable

Tags: c++

In C++, when I assign an array variable passed as a parameter to constructor to a class variable which is pointer, it takes garbage value. What is the reason behind it.

Here, in the SegTree constructor, assigning setbits(parameter value) to class variable(first line that is commented in the constructor) saves garbage value in it.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0)
// #define int long long
#define ends ' '
#define endl '\n'
#define pb push_back
#define INFYNODE node(INT_MAX, INT_MIN)

const int maxn = 2e5+5;

int a[maxn][6];

class node
{
public:
    int mn, mx;
    node(){mn = INT_MAX, mx = INT_MIN;}
    node(int _mn, int _mx){mn = _mn, mx = _mx;}
};

class SegTree
{
public:
    int *setbits, k, n;
    int *arr;



    node *tree;

    SegTree(int n, int k, int Setbits[])
    {
        // this->setbits = Setbits;
        this->setbits = new int[k];
        this->k = k;
        this->n = n;
        this->arr = new int[n+1];
        this->tree = new node[(n+1)<<2];

        for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i)setbits[i] = Setbits[i];

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            {
                arr[i] += a[i][j]*(setbits[j] ? -1 : 1);
            }
        }
        build(1, 1, n);
    }

    void display()
    {

        // cout << this->setbits[0] << '\n';
        for(int i = 1; i <= (n<<2); i++)
        {
            cerr << i << ' ' << tree[i].mn << ' ' << tree[i].mx << '\n';
        }
    }

    void merge(node &a, node &b, node &c)
    {
        c.mn = min(a.mn, b.mn);
        c.mx = max(a.mx, b.mx);
    }

    void build(int cur, int l, int r)
    {
        if(l == r)
        {
            tree[cur].mn = tree[cur].mx = arr[l];
            return;
        }
        int m = (l+r)>>1;
        build(cur<<1, l, m);
        build((cur<<1)+1, m+1, r);
        merge(tree[(cur<<1)], tree[(cur<<1)+1], tree[cur]);
    }

    node query(int cur, int l, int r, int ql, int qr)
    {
        if(l == ql and r == qr)
            return tree[cur];

        int m = (l+r)>>1;

        if(qr <= m)return query(cur<<1, l, m, ql, qr);

        else if(ql > m)return query((cur<<1)+1, m+1, r, ql, qr);

        else
        {
            node n1 = query(cur<<1, l, m, ql, m);
            node n2 = query((cur<<1)+1, m+1, r, m+1, qr);
            node ret;
            merge(n1, n2, ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    void update_array(int idx, int new_val[])
    {
        arr[idx] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            a[idx][i] = new_val[i];
            arr[idx] += new_val[i]*(setbits[i] ? -1 : 1);
        }
        update(1, 1, n, idx);
    }

    void update(int n, int l, int r, int idx)
    {
        if(l == r)
        {
            tree[n].mn = tree[n].mx = arr[idx];
            return;
        }
        int m = (l+r)>>1;
        if(idx <= m)update(n<<1, l, m, idx);
        else update((n<<1)+1, m+1, r, idx);
        merge(tree[(n<<1)], tree[(n<<1)+1], tree[n]);
    }
};


int32_t main()
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
        freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    IOS;

    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    int lim = 1<<k;

    vector<SegTree*> v(lim);

    for(int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
    {
        int setbits[k];
        memset(setbits, 0, sizeof setbits);
        for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        {
            if(i & (1<<j))
            {
                setbits[j] = 1;
            }
        }
        v[i] = new SegTree(n, k, setbits);
    }

    int q;
    cin >> q;

    int new_val[k];

    int haha = 0;

    while(q--)
    {
        int type;
        cin >> type;
        if(type == 1)
        {
            int j;
            cin >> j;

            for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
            {
                cin >> new_val[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
            {
                v[i]->update_array(j, new_val);
                // v[i]->display();
                // cerr << "\n\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int l, r;
            cin >> l >> r;
            int ans = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
            {
                node tmp = v[i]->query(1, 1, n, l, r);
                ans = max(ans, tmp.mx-tmp.mn);
            }
            cout << ans << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer. Use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: note that for the question it is actually more important to see the broken code rather than the fixed one. I was rather confused because its not in the code that you assign the parameter to the pointer member (comments is something I usually do ignore). Also for completeness it would be good if you show how you call the constructor

Comment: Can you include an example of the object instantiation, ideally a simple main() function showing the usage? It'll illustrate you're issue better.

Comment: Hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to iterate through the bitmask and passing the set bits' array to the object's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correctly, you're having problems copying an array. A quick bit of Google-Fu can resolve this. EG: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/199358/

However, you're question is ambiguous so I might have the wrong end of the stick. See comments.